# organization and departments hierarchy database schema

Tags: mysql, sql, django, database-design, database-schema

I have a database design in django that have the following tables:

- **organization table**

  - *id*
  - *name*
  - *contact*
- **department table**

  - *name*
  - *parent* (another department self referencing )
  - *organization* (referencing the organization table if this is the top department only)

**How to  inherit the organization relationship instead of having to set it every time i am creating a new department?**

**Edit:**

I am just wondering if there is a better design :
In this design I am having a null field for each department (organization ID). In real life only one department should have a value which is the top parent. The other child departments shouldn't have an organization id associated to it, because the association is already made through the parent dep.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by inherit. Do you mean that all the child departments should have the organization field automatically created same as the parent department?

Comment: Is this a syntax question?  If so, let's see your incomplete `INSERT` statement so we can add to it.

Comment: I have updated my question